# How to update a custom control bar with MPMoviePlayer for IOS?

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'am developing an iOS app with the MPMoviePlayer, I use custom controls (play, pause, stop, seek...) the problem is to update my progress time bar in real time... is there a notification to update it?? I though about calling a timer but it isn't gonna pass the apple approbation... some ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a timer - Apple will not reject your app because you are polling a property using a timer. I would suggest you to use a delay of 0.5 seconds.

You may also try KVO but AFAIK `currentPlaybackTime` is not key value compliant.